# Why does a loop gain phase margin plot start from 180?

Tags: bode-plot

Bode plots are used to plot the the magnitude and phase of the loop gain - the mulitplication between the feedforward gain and the feedback factor, nothing else.

[image]

Why do some plots start at -180 and not 0? The loop gain phase plot should not include the negative feedback, correct? It makes more sense to me to start at 0 and then shift -90 for each pole.

**It makes sense to me that a closed loop bode plot should start at -180 due to the negative feedback being always present. But for an open loop loop gain bode plot, shouldn't it always start at 0?**

Comment: Assume this is using the inverting input thus -180

Comment: Are the circuits inverting or non-inverting?

Comment: Looks like 2 low frequency (or origin) poles, since your magnitude slope is about -40 dB/decade.  Each pole contributes 90 degrees of phase shift.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes, that assumption would be part of the full closed loop Bode. But if we are plotting just the Loop Gain, it has no knowledge of how the system is hooked up, so we shouldn't see at phase shift at the start. The only phase shift should be due to the poles.

Comment: If using the non-inverting input then your DC gain would not be the same it would be 1 + |Av-| =2 which is not the same  and then the phase would be 0 towards DC

Comment: You only show one graph there without a lot of concrete scenarios. I can say with regards to op amps, that the relationship between vin+ and vin- and vout can change depending on how it is all hooked up as well as how many stages are used.  Some cases will give 180 Open Loop, others 0.

Comment: @pat an opamp under open-loop condition is quite another thing that the "loop gain" of a system with feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "loop gain"?

It is the gain of the **complete** loop when opened at a suitable point (without changing loading conditions). That means: Of course, it should include the negative sign at the summing junction (negative feedback). As a consequence, the phase of the loop gain function must start (very low frequencies) at -180 deg (negative DC feedback for a stable operating point).

Remark: During circuit simulation, this condition will be automatically fulfilled.

In this respect, we should not forget that there are many circuits (in particular active filter topologies) where the feedback signal is NOT connected to the first opamps inverting node because the necessary phase inversion takes place anywhere in the feedback loop (another amplifier, inverting).

General rule: Any loop with negative feedback for very low frequencies must start at a phase shift of -180deg. This applies, of course, also to oscillatory feedback circuits (positive loop gain for a  frequency only).

(Therefore, the first sentence of your question - "*nothing else*" - is not correct. And also your last sentence - *"closed-loop Bode plot should start at -180deg due to negative feedback*" - is not correct. The sign of the closed-loop gain is not determined by feedback but by the configuration (inverting or non-inverting).